# non consecutive count report - sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have the following  count

```
SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN DeliveryCode = 2 THEN 1
                 WHEN Customer_id <> Customer_id THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 
                 END) AS col
```

Trying to do a count where in date order,

Date 1
if a customer fails to pick up their parcel, then 1, if not 0

Date 2
if they failed do it again the next date, then 1,

Date 3
if they on the next date, manage to pick up the parcel, then count returns to 0 for that customer ID.

I got the above working nearly, but cant get the total to go back to 0, when customer

But what I would also like the count to do, if the customer picks up their parcel the count goes to 0, but if they start failing to pick up their parcel's again, in future dates, it starts accumulating the 1 again

```
Customer_id     DATE     DeliveryCode
1             01/01/2017        2
1             02/01/2017        2
1             03/01/2017        2
2             01/01/2017        1
3             01/01/2017        1
3             02/01/2017        1
4             01/01/2017        2
4             02/01/2017        2
4             03/01/2017        1

ID 1 will equal 3
ID 2 will equal 0
ID 3 will equal 0
ID 4 will equal 0
```

Any ideas please

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data and desired result would helpful.

Comment: Pls add some sample data and expected output

Comment: What is `Customer_id <> Customer_id` supposed to accomplish, is this some sort of exotic ISNULL check?

Comment: added some data, but I cannot get it to format on here

Comment: What happens if a customer has different parcels on different days?  What delivery code is "Picked up?" 1?  or anything but 2?

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that delivery attempts stop after a success (1) then we can look for the max date for a customer then use it and it's deliverycode to check if we need to reset to 0

[RexTester Tested](http://rextester.com/TAWS56360):  (note @params not defined in rex tester as scope of question has changed)

```
SELECT A.Customer_ID
     , sum(case A.deliveryCode when 2 then 1 else 0 end) * 
       min(Case when A.mDate = MaxDel.MDate and DeliveryCode <> 2 then 0 else 1 end)
       as ActiveConcurrentFailedDelivery
FROM SO50411005 A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Customer_ID, max(mDate) mDate
           FROM SO50411005
           GROUP BY Customer_ID) MaxDel
  on A.Customer_ID = MaxDel.Customer_ID
WHERE A.mDate between @paramStart and @ParamEnd
GROUP BY A.CUSTOMER_ID
```

Results:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------------------+
|    | Customer_ID | ActiveConcurrentFailedDelivery |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------+
|  1 |           1 |                              3 |
|  2 |           2 |                              0 |
|  3 |           3 |                              0 |
|  4 |           4 |                              0 |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: having difficulty linking this within my query, as need this as a count column , can you please help - All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists. need this to count when people select two dates in a report. please help

Comment: why a union?  wouldn't this just be a derived table which you join to on customer_ID?  (wrap the above in ()'s add it as a LEFT join to your query, alias this derived table and join on customer_ID.  I'm not sure what you're really after now; the nature of the question is changing which makes answering your comment a new question really.  And you never really answered what should happen if a customer has multiple deliveries/parcles out at once.

Comment: needs to be a count within, as using report builder 3.0, thus if a user changes the date parameters in the report thus the count will have to change dynamically. please help

Comment: I can't.  I'm not familiar with Report builder 3.0. Now I think all you need is a where clause `where mdate between ParmStart and ParamEnd` and if this is left joined to your existing query that already has that on the date and done then your done.  if date only exists on this table then left join on customer ***and** derived table's mdate between paramStart and ParamEnd  but maybe the tool only allows you to union, intersect and except?  I don't know...  I would suggest a new question with report builder 3.0 as the tag reference this question and what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have managed to join the count as suggested , using an INNER Join, just issues now where clause part to add ...where date between @startdate and enddate - please help

Comment: Each reporting tool will be different on how it manages parameters: you'd have to read up on how ti handles them: maybe: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-parameters-report-builder-and-report-designer?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: hi - sorry to be a pain, I have tried playing around with the script but having issues where to add my where clause for ...where mdate between ParmStart and ParamEnd , I have tried adding it by / both each from, and I get error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would go on the left table (A) in my example in the where clause as illustrated in the updated answer.  Bear in mind I've no idea how Report Builder handles this type of action; but something similar should work in standard T-SQL  Note I had to specify which dataset/table I wanted filtered.  Since I think you want all the records for a customer between the dates provided, using it on (A) instead of dataset MaxDel means you get all customer dates between the range provided.

Comment: Hi, sorry in no reply, been on holi bob's..issue where I can limit the where  ActiveConcurrentFailedDelivery =1 , I keep getting the error... cannot be bound please help